# MYSQL never stops trying to connect if IP is correct, but port or instance is wrong

Tags: java, mysql

I am getting a real strange behaviour from Java and MYSQL if I write the wrong connection information.
Say for example the correct connection information is :

```
ip: localhost
port: 8889
instance:test
```

If I connect with this information, everything is fine, but if I change the port number or the instance name to something invalid, the code never stops trying to connect. If I enter a wrong IP, no problem, the code stops trying and provide me with a error message.

This is my code:

```
  try {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     System.out.println("Driver Loaded.");
     String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + mySqlAdress + ":" + myPort + "/" + sqlInstance +"?connectTimeout=3000";
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "root");

     System.out.println("Got Connection. " + conn);

 } catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println("FAILED.");

}
```

As you can see, I am now testing with ?conncetionTimeOut=3000. I have tried both this and setting a timeout on the DriverManager. No luck, code never stops trying.

Comment: sqlInstance  is nothing but your database name,if you give a database name that is not present then it may give you some problem

Comment: Ye, but the hole point is that I can't control what the user inputs. I need to check the connection even if it's wrong.

Comment: Then change your code,1st find if the DB exists or not if it does then do as per your above post if not then ask the user to valid DB name

Comment: That's what I am currently doing, that's why I do the get connection before I execute any queries at all?

Comment: No you are not doing as I said.You are directly passing DB name without checking if it exists or not

Answer (score 2):

You can use **autoReconnect** attribute like below

```
?autoReconnect=false
```

I hope it will resolve your query

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add : socketTimeout=3000, for anyone wondering. Thanks to @sanket for suggesting the autoRecconect parameter.